# How do I upgrade apache kafka in linux

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a novice question on kafka upgrade.. This is the 1st time I'm upgrading my kafka in Linux.

My current version is "kafka_2.11-1.0.0.tgz".. when I initially setup I had a folder named kafka_2.11-1.0.0.

Now I downloaded a new version "kafka_2.12-2.3.0.tgz". If I extract it is going to create a new folder kafka_2.12-2.3.0 which will result in 2 independent kafka with server.properties.

As per documentation I have to update server.properties with below 2 properties..

inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3
log.message.format.version=2.3

How does this affect if it is going to install in a new directory with new server.properties?

How can I merge server.properties & do the upgrade? Please share if you have documents or steps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's fairly simple to upgrade Kafka. 
It would have been easier for you to separate config files from binary directories, as a result, from what I understand, your config file remains with the untar package folder.
You can put the config file in /etc/kafka next time you'll package it on your Linux server.

What you can do here is , after untar your kafka_2.12-2.3.0.tgz file, you just copy the former server.properties ( and other config files you might use as well) and replace the one in the `2.3.0` arborescence.

But be careful, for `inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3` and `log.message.format.version=2.3` parameters, you must first specify the former version for those parameters ( and message.format is not mandatory to change, double check the doc for this one) before doing your rolling restart.

If you are using 1.0 now, just put the following :
`inter.broker.protocol.version=1.0` and `log.message.format.version=1.0`
then restart your brokers one by one (using the new package folder this time)

Then edit them again as follows :
`inter.broker.protocol.version=2.3` and `log.message.format.version=2.3` and do a second rolling restart.

Then you should be good

More details here :
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_3_0

Yannick